# Store Filename as separate variables in PowerShell - based on specific character

Tags: powershell

I have a vendor file that is stored in a specific format and I would like to use PowerShell to convert the file name into three separate variables which I would then use to pass to a stored procedure that would be executed.

The file format would look like:

> AA_BBBBB_YYYYMMDD.xlsx

For instance, the following is an example of a current Excel file:

```
TX_StampingFee_20210303.xlsx
```

The 1st characters will generally be a US state abbreviation but not always - so it could be 2 or 3 characters long.  The 2nd section is the type of fee the Excel file contains while the last section is the date in a YYYYMMDD format.

What I would like to do is have PowerShell read the file name and separate the name into three separate variables:

```
$State
$Fee
$Date
```

What I have so far will list the Excel file in the directory and then I tried to split the name up - but I believe the file extension on the name is causing an error. How can I split this file name into separate variables based off the "_" ( underscore ) character?

```
Foreach ($file in Get-Childitem "C:\PowerShell\Test\*.xlsx") {
    $file.name
}

$filenames = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowerShell\Test\*.xlsx" -Directory).Name

Write-Host $filenames

$chararray = $filenames.Split("_")
$chararray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the basename which is the filename minus the extension. Then when you split into 3 parts you can directly put those into 3 variables.

```
Foreach ($file in Get-Childitem "C:\PowerShell\Test\*.xlsx") {
    $State,$Fee,$Date = $file.basename.split('_')
    Write-Host State: $State Fee: $Fee Date: $Date
}
```

Comment: Actually your example file has 4 sections. Will it be typical that your middle portion have an underscore as well?

Comment: We can have the vendor not including an underscore when describing the fees so then we would only have two underscores in the file name.

Comment: OK good. You may edit your example file to reduce possible confusion on future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BaseName` rather than the `Name` property to get the filename without the extension.

Then, if you trust the pattern of the filenames, you can index into your array with a range to join your 1+ fee type substrings into a single string:

```
$filenames = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowerShell\Test\*.xlsx" -File).BaseName

if ($filenames) {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$fees = @()
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$states = @()
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$dates = @()

    foreach ($name in $filenames) {
        $chararray = $name.Split("_")
        $arrlen = $chararray.length

        if ($arrlen -ge 3) {
            $states += $chararray[0]
            $fees += $chararray[1..$arrlen-2] -join '_'
            $dates += $chararray[$arrlen])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP asked about files - not `-Directory`!  ;-)  ... and you are building your `$chararray` from all `$filenames` (well actually directory names) and not just from the current one.

Comment: True and true. Should have written from scratch rather than copy & paste. Editing.

Comment: If I got it right this `$fees += $chararray[1..$arrlen-2] -join '_'` should be this `$fees += $chararray[1..($arrlen-2)] -join '_'` and this `$dates += $chararray[$arrlen])` should be this actually `$dates += $chararray[($arrlen -1)]`  ... you may try your code before posting it. ;-)

Comment: Regardless of all that: I could imagine that it would be good to have a file name actually together with the parts of its name to be able to process them together. ;-)

Comment: If you go through the extra step the use the .NET arraylist then use it properly and dont use += to add elements use the .Add() method. Its multitude faster.For example a simple loop from 0 to 50000 adding the value of $x to an Array using += takes 53.23 seconds . THe exact same loop using the.Add() method takes just 82.14 milliseconds